# Are the mappings linear?

Tags: functional-analysis

$$
\begin{array}{l}
T_{7}: \mathcal{C}^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{0}(\mathbb{R}),\left(T_{7} f\right)(x):=f^{\prime \prime}(x) \\
T_{8}: \mathcal{C}^{1}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{0}(\mathbb{R}),\left(T_{8} f\right)(x):=f(x) \cdot f^{\prime}(x)
\end{array}
$$

Hello guys, I'm trying to find if the following mappings are Linear or not? But I'm having difficulties understanding how the 2 rules of showing linearity are applied for differential functions as shown in the Image. Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, for the first is simple : $T_7(\lambda f+g) = (\lambda f+g)'' = \lambda f'' + g'' = \lambda T_7(f)+T_7(g)$, so it is linear.

Comment: $T_8(\lambda f + g )= (\lambda f + g)(\lambda f +g)' = (lambda f+g)(\lambda f' + g')$ hummm the product will expand and you will have something like $T_8(\lambda f +g) = \lambda T_8(f)+T_8(g) + z(f,g)$, where $z(f,g)$ is not 0.

Comment: @LuisFelipe Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the basic definitión which are

> A transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ over $W,V$ vectorial spaces, then
> $T$ is linear if
> $$T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$$
> $$T(\alpha u)=\alpha T(u)$$
> Notice that when you need to know if a given aplication is Lineal you need to take
> $u,v\in V$ and calculate $T(u+v)$ and $T(\alpha u)$ (according to the rule given by the application) and compare it with $T(u)+T(v)$ and $\alpha T(u)$ and see if the expresions are the same
> Remember that $\alpha \in F$ that is $\alpha$ is an escalar in some field $F$